# why the output is starting from 1 instead of 3 ? if the value of i becomes 3 , the output should be start with 3.?

Tags: javascript, html

this is FOR LOOP that output the numbers 1 3 5 7 9

here the value of i is 3, then output should start from 3 ..?

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 var text = "";
 var i;

 for(i = 0; i<=9; i = i + 2  )
 {
     text = i + 1 +"<br>";
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you set it's value to be 3? And even if you have set it above, in the for loop you are initialising it with 0 and hence it prints 1 ( after adding 1 in first line of for loop ).

Comment: you are starting with 0 thats why it is displaying 1,3,5,7,9

Comment: `here the value of i is 3` no, `i` in the for loop starts at 0 then goes to 2, 4, 6, then 8 - it's never 3

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: If you set `for(i=3;...)` then the output would start from `4`, because of the `i + 1` inside the loop.

Comment: Learn how for loop works first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your given code has value i=3 ,it starts displaying from 4 instead of 3 ,because within for loop you are setting the content as i+1 if you want it to be 3,just change it to i in the loop,which means if it has to display 1,3,5,7,9 instead of starting from 0 ,start from 1

check this snippet

```html
this is FOR LOOP that output the numbers 1 3 5 7 9

 here the value of i is 3, then output should start from 3 ..?

 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i=3;

for(i = 3; i<=9; i = i + 2  )
{
 text = i +"<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or else you can even consider doing as the following

```js
var text = "";
var i;

for (i = 3; i <= 9;) {
  var content = (i % 2 == 0) ? i + 1 : i;
  text = content + "<br>";

  if (i % 2 == 0)
    i = i + 3;
  else
    i = i + 2;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thanx  ... this is really helpful ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might be confused about how for loops are executed.

1. Initialization block is executed `i = 0;`
2. Continuation condition is checked `i <= 9`
3. If (2) is `true`, the for loop's body is executed, if `false`, stop looping
4. Final expression block is executed `i += 2`
5. Goto (2)

Therefore, when you get to the first execution of the for loop's body, `i` is `0`, so `1` is output

Comment: ohhhh okyyy ... ur last line cleared my doubt ... tx :)

Answer (score 0):

your initialized it from 0 that's why? instead initialize it from i=3 n check then.

Comment: thanx but actually i just want to know that why 1 is on top instead of 3 ? i just want explanation of it

Answer (score 0):

```
for (stmt 1; stmt 2; stmt 3) {
    //code to be executed
}
```

stmt 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.

stmt 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block).

stmt 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed.

So initialy value of i is set to 0, so it is printing 1.

To get value starting from 3 you need to change value of i, here is modified code. Please check

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i;

for(i = 2; i<=9; i = i + 2  )
{
 text = i + 1 +"<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

OP: 
3
5
7
9

Comment: thanx but actually i just want to know that why 1 is on top instead of 3 ? i just want explanation of it .